# Creating a table with date as range partition in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, teradata

I am new to SQL Server coding. Please let me know how to create a table with range partition on date in SQL Server

A similar syntax in teradata would be the following (a table is created with order date as range partition over year 2012 with each day as single partition  )

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DATA (   
   ORDER_NUM INTEGER NOT NULL 
   ,CUST_NUM INTEGER 
   ,ORDER_DATE DATE 
   ,ORDER_TOT DECIMAL(10,2) 
) 
PRIMARY INDEX(ORDER_NUM) 
PARTITION BY (RANGE_N ( ORDER_DATE BETWEEN DATE ‘2012-01-01’ AND DATE 2012-12-31 EACH INTERVAL ‘1’ DAY));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of creating partitioned table is described on MSDN as follows:

`Creating a partitioned table or index typically happens in four parts:
 1. Create a filegroup or filegroups and corresponding files that will hold the partitions specified by the partition scheme.
 2. Create a partition function that maps the rows of a table or index into partitions based on the values of a specified column.
 3. Create a partition scheme that maps the partitions of a partitioned table or index to the new filegroups.
 4. Create or modify a table or index and specify the partition scheme as the storage location.`

You can find code samples [on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx).

Comment: Hi shree, can you include the total syntax conversion for my query

Comment: @user3534342 I'm not sure that would add much value, considering I am already referring to the official documentation even in this answer.